# How to retrieve the unsaved data from Rstudio

Tags: r

I was trying to crawl the data using R, however, when the data is accessed for the 60000th data entry, my RStudio crashed out of the limited memory volume.

When I checked the default directory, I found nothing. I wonder if there is any method to retrieve the unsaved data?

Any idea would be helpful!

Comment: I guess you cannot retrieve these data, since you didn't save them. You can add a command to save your data before that mentioned number.

Comment: Thx @patL, so I cannot find back the data?

Comment: No, you cannot have your data back...